# SetText method of arrayAdapter for listView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Hey guys I am doing my first android assignment. There is sth wrong with the arrayAdapter class and it cause the breaking of the application.

Here is the class for my data

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Movie {

public String movie_name;
public String movie_director;
public String movie_actor;
public String movie_genre;
public String movie_time;
public String movie_location ; 

// constructor
public Movie(String movie_name, String movie_director, String movie_actor, String movie_genre, String movie_time, String movie_location){
    this.movie_name = movie_name;
    this.movie_director= movie_director;
    this.movie_actor= movie_actor;
    this.movie_genre = movie_genre;
    this.movie_time= movie_time;
    this.movie_location= movie_location;
}

}
```

Here is the class for showing data

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Show_Movie extends Activity {

public static UserSQLiteHelper usdbh;
public SQLiteDatabase db;
public Movie[] Movie_data = new Movie[20];

AlertDialog alertDialogStores;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_layout);
    Button showMovie = (Button)findViewById(R.id.show_movie_button);


    showMovie.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){         

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            usdbh = new UserSQLiteHelper(Show_Movie.this, "DBMovie", null,1);
            db = usdbh.getReadableDatabase();

            //getting data from SQL
            String[] fields = new String[]{"name","director","actor","genre","time","location"};
            Cursor c = db.query("movie", fields, null, null, null, null,null);              
            int i= 0;

            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {                           
                do{
                String name = c.getString(0);
                String director = c.getString(1);
                String actor= c.getString(2);
                String genre = c.getString(3);
                String time = c.getString(4);                   
                String location= c.getString(5);                    
                Movie_data[i]= new Movie(name, director, actor, genre, time, location);

                //checking whether getting data succeed 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Movie_data[i].movie_name + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

                i++;
            }while(c.moveToNext());

            }//end if
            db.close();

            //Setting adapter and ListView layout
            ArrayAdapterItem adapter = new ArrayAdapterItem (Show_Movie.this, R.layout.list_view_row_item, Movie_data);
            ListView listViewItems = new ListView(Show_Movie.this);
            listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
            listViewItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListenerListViewItem());

            //show the listView
            alertDialogStores = new AlertDialog.Builder(Show_Movie.this).setView(listViewItems).setTitle("Stores").show();

        }//onClick method ends


    });
}//create method ends


}
```

And here is my arrayAdapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

Context mContext;
int layoutResourceID;
Movie data[] = null;

//constructor
public ArrayAdapterItem(Context mContext, int layoutResourceID, Movie[] data) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceID, data);    
    this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
    this.mContext= mContext;
    this.data= data;
}   

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    if(convertView==null){
        //inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Show_Movie)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent,false);         
    }

    //movie item based on the position
    Movie movie = data[position];

    //get the TextView and then set the text(movie name) and tag(show_Movie.i) values
    TextView textViewItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);


    textViewItem.setText(movie.movie_name);


    return convertView;


}
}
```

And when I run it with a emulator and click the button "Show me the movie", it crushes and  gives me this log

```
    at com.example.fristassignment.ArrayAdapterItem.getView(ArrayAdapterItem.java:56)
```

After double clicking it it highlight the setText() method in ArrayAdapterItem.java

Does any body know what s wrong?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: The full log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at     com.example.fristassignment.ArrayAdapterItem.getView(ArrayAdapterItem.java:56)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at     android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 D/dalvikvm(692): GC_CONCURRENT freed 154K, 3% free 11036K/11271K, paused 77ms+19ms, total 265ms
 I/Process(692): Sending signal. PID: 692 SIG: 9
```

Comment: does R.layout. list_view_row_item contain R.id.textViewItem?

Comment: @blackbelt Yes. Actually it is the only thing it contains

Comment: @Aniruddha It s till the same log and crush. Either way thanks mate

Comment: line at ArrayAdapterItem.java:56 ?

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya "textViewItem.setText(movie.movie_name);"

Comment: Just debug it and tell which one is null textViewItem or movie.movie_name ?

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya movie.movie_name

Answer (score 0):

Please provide 56 Line in ArrayAdapterItem Class?

Try this Solutions

```
public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

Activity mActivity;
int layoutResourceID;
Movie data[] = null;

//constructor
public ArrayAdapterItem(Activity mContext, int layoutResourceID, Movie[] data) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceID, data);    
    this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
    this.mActivity= mContext;
    this.data= data;
}   

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    if(convertView==null){
        //inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent, false);
    }
    //movie item based on the position
    Movie movie = data[position];
    //get the TextView and then set the text(movie name) and tag(show_Movie.i) values
    TextView textViewItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
    textViewItem.setText(movie.movie_name);


    return convertView;


}
```

}

Comment: What is this **NPE?**

Comment: textViewItem.setText(movie.movie_name);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

Context mContext;
int layoutResourceID;
Movie data[] = null;

//constructor
public ArrayAdapterItem(Context mContext, int layoutResourceID, Movie[] data) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceID, data);    
    this.layoutResourceID = layoutResourceID;
    this.mContext= mContext;
    this.data= data;
}   

  public class Holder
        {
            TextView textViewItem;


        }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    if(convertView==null){
        //inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Show_Movie)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceID, parent,false);         
    }
   Holder holder=new Holder();
    //movie item based on the position
    Movie movie = data[position];

    //get the TextView and then set the text(movie name) and tag(show_Movie.i) values
     holder.textViewItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);


    holder.textViewItem.setText(movie.movie_name);


    return convertView;


}
}
```

Comment: you should not give full code because this is his/her assignment.